# Why does Windows run more efficiently than most Linux distros on my old laptop?

Tags: linux, windows, laptop

I have an old Lenovo G40-30 80FY laptop with a Pentium N3530 processor, 8Gb of RAM and a 120Gb SATA SSD.

I believe that it will run most of Linux distributions flawlessly.

But the fact is that it's worse. Slow operations, buggy UI and sometimes the system just crashes. I can't even open IntelliJ with a small project with 3-4 Chromium tabs. Moreover, the laptop is pretty hot due to being a fanless laptop (for casual laptop maybe).

Then I tried to switch to Windows 10, and it runs smoothly. I can now open at least 2 projects on IntelliJ, some Chrome tabs, Postman, and DB tools without any hiccup. The operations are still not really fast, but they're faster than any Linux distribution I've tried. That's made me wonder for some nights.

I tried Debian Gnome/KDE, Ubuntu, Mint Cinnamon, Arch (with KDE and LXDE for some times) and so on.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong when using Linux on my laptop?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak it's a Lenovo G40-30 80FY with a slight upgrade of 8Gb RAM and 120Gb SSD.

Comment: Please could you better define "runs more smoothly" on a reproducible example?

Comment: Linux isnt - always - optimized for Lap Tops. So it might be, that your processor runs hot and steps down. It would be more slower then, as it could perform. But the picture you draw doesnt seem to be correct. Linux, depending on what gui you use, runs much better. Maybe you have enabled UI effeckts, without having installed drivers for your GPU.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak for eg: I'm a web developer, so my routine is: Back end projects on IntelliJ, i left my microservice project in my workstation, so only one IntelliJ. 4-5 tabs of chromium, Postman, Robo3T for db management, and visual studio code for front end like react code in here. Slow operations on Linux, sometimes crashes. But with windows, with similar operations, it's run wildly, not the fastest, but haven't had experience like on Linux. Btw, I used Linux for over 2 years now. My product workstation is still run Debian day by day :3

Comment: @WGRM even when I use some DE without effect like LXDE or XFCE, the performance is still worse at some point. Like can't even load Chromium new tabs, it's take over 10 seconds but CPU and RAM still in reasonable amount. That's weird!

Comment: In BIOS, are you sure to have AHCI instead of IDE SATA mode enabled?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak pretty sure

Comment: Make it 100% sure please -- have a look.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Okay, I will have a look at it when I got home, @ work atm :D

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak It's AHCI for sure